# Replace all occurences of pattern in the string by another pattern using MySQL regexp_replace

Tags: mysql, regexp-replace

I have a column containing a list of ISBN separated by a comma. I wanted to extract some information from the string by using regxp_replace function to replace all the occurrences of pattern in the string but it returns only returns the last matched occurrence of the pattern in the list of ISBNs. I have used the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('123-4567-8-9012-0, 123-4567-89-012-0, 123-4567-890-12-0, 123-4567-8901-2-0, 123-45678-9-012-3',
'(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)', '\\2-\\3')  prefixes;
```

The query returns the last matching occurrence of the pattern in the string.

```
45678-9
```

I wanted the following result:

```
4567-8, 4567-89, 4567-890, 4567-8901, 45678-9
```

I'd appreciate it if I could get the solution using regexp_replace or similar functions.

Thank you.

Comment: I am fairly certain that when using capture groups MySQL will interpret the pattern as applying to the entire input.  This means your requirement is difficult to phrase because it is a denormalized CSV list of ISBNs.  You should first focus on getting each ISBN onto a separate record.

Comment: Actually, the table is normalized but the generated csv has all the ISBNs concatenated using group_concat. Each record has only one ISBN. The table is normalized. I will have to perform the regular expression while generating such result.